# how text to speech works in android

Tags: android, text-to-speech, android-speech-api

I am creating an android application using text to speech capability I used the built in text to speech
 I only want to know how it has been developed and maintained in the android SDK, if any one knows a termed paper about developing text to speech in android i'll be blessed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/tts-for-android/EzXyyqG7cvw) will help.  Also, an abstract class for TTS Engine Implementation was introduced in API Level 14. Check this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeechService.html). You can also read this [information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_synthesis) about speech synthesis to guide you on how it should be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

by luck i was working in this also , take my code

```
package com.example.texttospeech;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener, OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    EditText editxt;
        Button b1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



        tts = new  TextToSpeech(this , this);
        editxt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read);
        b1.setOnClickListener(this);
    }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.read:
            convert_text();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }

    }
    private void convert_text() {
        String speech = editxt.getText().toString();
        tts.speak(speech, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);

    }
    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
            if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){  
                Log.e("DEBUG" , "Language Not Supported");}
            else{
                b1.setEnabled(true);
                convert_text();
            }

        }
        else{
            Log.i("DEBUG" , "MISSION FAILED");
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (tts != null){
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
    }

}
```

mylayout  activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="21sp"
        android:layout_marginTop="23dp"
        android:text="Text To Speech Test" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:ems="10" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/read"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="46dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:text="Read" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This is using the inbuilt one. He/She wants to know how it's built/implemented